# how to install an apk present in sdcard on single click?

Tags: android

I want to install an apk present in the sdcard of the device from third party application which will be having a install button. It should install on single click of button.

Comment: you need administrator privileges if i'm not mistaking.

Comment: Triggered from an ordinary SDK app, installation will take as many clicks as the OS wants it to take. You do not have control over that aspect of the installation process. All you can do is ask to start the installation process (e.g., via `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your third party app has Storage Read Permission then read the apk using below Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
apkName=YourApk.apk
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/YourPath/"+apkName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```